# Terminating excel process

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Having read many threads on here about not using double dots when referencing excel com objects, I decided to implement it.

It worked up until I came to doing in my loop.

Here is my loop. Note that it works if I comment this out:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i] = dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;

            var cell = excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i];
            var fontSetter = cell.Font;
            fontSetter.Bold = true; //Bolds the header row

            // Garbage collecting
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(fontSetter);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cell);
        }
```

Shouldn't my code dispose of them variables correctly?

Here is my full code:

```
[Code removed]
```

I am trying to follow the steps over at [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp) (the second answer)

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to get this right.  But I'm surprised the following even compiles:

```
excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i] = dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText; 
var cell = excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i];
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i].Value = dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText; 
var cell = excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i];
```

which should be replaced by:

```
var cell = excelWorkbook.Cells[1, i]; 
cell.Value = dgv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
```

I don't see the point in your `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` calls, since you make them before `cell` and `fontSetter` go out of scope.

Finally the calls to `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` should probably be in a finally block, so that they will be executed even if an Exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried doing that by puttng the full loop in a try and then using finally, but It wasen't able to find the variables. Maybe because they are declared in the loop?

Comment: Yes, the try/finally would have to be inside the loop.  Each time through the look, you reference a new cell and its font, and you have to release all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by following the method specified by nightcoder in [How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp).

You don't need to reference anything and has the least clutter of them all, it closes the process by its ID. Hope this helps someone who comes in looking.